# can't figure out correct Bitbucket REST API 1.0 - still getting http 404

Tags: rest, http, bitbucket

i'm trying to add user to a Bitbucket group by rest api (version 1.0), my call:

`curl -k -u user:pass-X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://server/bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/groups/$USER/$g/members/$USER/" --data '{}'`

as i found guide here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/groups-endpoint-296093143.html

but still getting error: 

`11:34:16   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
11:34:16                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
11:34:16 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   216    0   214  100     2   1018      9 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1023
11:34:16 404null for uri: https://server/bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/groups/testUser/test/members/testUser/  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current`

can someone pls. help me?

Comment: solved. <code>curl -v -k -u user:passs-X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "server/bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/admin/groups/add-user" --data '{"context": "$g","itemName": "$USER"}'</code>

Comment: That documentation is for Bitbucket Cloud, but you're using Bitbucket Server.

Answer (score 0):

solved. `curl -v -k -u user:passs-X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "server/bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/admin/groups/add-user" --data '{"context": "$g","itemName": "$USER"}'`